# Calculate Unspent using private keys

Tags: bitcoin-core, address, balance, listunspent

Can we calculate unspent of addresses which are generated from other node server if we are having private/public key of those addresses?

Answer (score 1):

If you have just a pair of private and public keys, you would need a little more information.

A single public key can control Bitcoin in a number of ways:

1. A direct p2pk output
2. A p2pkh output paying the hash of the public key
3. A p2sh output paying a script controlled by a set of public keys that may include keys other than the one you have
4. A p2wpkh segwit output paying the hash of the public key
5. A p2wsh output paying a script controlled by a set of public keys that may include keys other than the one you have

Without knowing which type of output you are looking for, the public key alone is not sufficient, especially for p2sh and p2wsh outputs where other keys are required to construct the address.

Once you know which output type to look for, you can use the `scantxoutset` RPC method of a node, or construct your own index similar to an explorer or Electrum server and query balances.

Comment: Thanks @Raghav. Can you please tell whether bitcoin-core support derivation path other than m/0'/0'/i. Is there any possibility for m/1'/0'/i or m/k'/0/i' where k: 1,2,3....& so on ?

Comment: It does not, as far as I'm aware

Comment: As far as i know bitcoincore support HD wallet creation but how we can create derivartion like m/1'/0' as m/0'/0' which is for default account 0 because i want to maintain user account in bitcoincore HD wallet.

Comment: You can't, you need to maintain a user->address mapping outside of bitcoind

Comment: yes. that's true but how we can calculate unspent of user->address mapping outside of bitcoind from any node?

Comment: You can use the `scantxoutset` RPC method if you are operating a Bitcoin node, or use a database synced against a Bitcoin node such as ElectrumX or Bitcore

Comment: Will check.Thanks @Raghav for the info.